# How to add an expansion file to an app

Tags: android, sqlite, notepad, apk-expansion-files

I'm a new app developer and I know the least about Android.
I've developed a Notepad.

I want to keep its installation size minimal and I would like to add options like fonts as an optional downloadable addon.

I do not have any code or logic of how to make that happen, but since I have seen this type of support in a few Android editing apps, it's definitely possible.

I need a full tutorial to help me do that in my application.
Kindly help me out of it.

My Notepad is a simple Note making app based on the tutorials provided by Google and uses SQLite database, it is heavily focused on themes and looks and has a very beautiful note sharing system.

You can check the app here [Easy Pad Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pickstyleworx.writer)

Comment: You need to divide your task into small isolated units, chase them one after the other.

Comment: Sorry i was not feeling so I didn't checked the Answer. So anyone can help me plzz..